# Проблемы с Less

Tags: css, wordpress, sublime-text-3, less

Установил less глобально. На Sublime Text 3 установил плагены Less и Less2css.
Все компелируется .less в .css, но браузер показывает старый стиль, как будто ни каких изменений не произошло. Ссылка на файл правильная. Может быть я какой плагин забыл установить? Сам сайт на wordpress.

Comment: Файл конфигурации или тот файл, в котором находятся ваши настройки для less ? Так не угадаешь в чем проблема. Возможно все таки вы ссылаетесь на неверный css

Answer (score 1):

Понял в чем проблема. При подключении стиля с помощью

```
wp_register_style( 'general_css', THEME_URL . '/css/general.css', array(), MY_THEME_VERSION, 'all');
```

из-за `MY_THEME_VERSION` почему-то грузится только старая версия файла, а новые изменения в файле не грузятся. Причем при изменение версии в файле style.css в корне темы новые стили начинают работать.